# Execute unique query after foreach loop php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have to update a mysql table with values that comes from array variable in size.
For that i was doing something like this but this code execute many query as the number of items on the array, and is hard to manage errors. 
how i can execute only one query but still using a foreach loop? 
the php version of server is so old does not support anything else than mysql_query.

```
foreach($decoded_array as $key=>$value)
                      {
                            if(!is_numeric($value))
                            {
                            $value = "'".$value."'";
                            }

                            echo $sql ="UPDATE table SET ".$key." = ".$value.";     
                            $res = mysql_query($sql);

                      }
```

Comment: Study prepared statements - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$set = "";
foreach($decoded_array as $key=>$value)
    $set .= ($set ? "," : "") . $key . "=" . (is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'".$value."'");
$sql = "UPDATE table SET " . $set;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

But im not sure using "'".$value."'" is safe. I prefer mysqli function escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $sql ="UPDATE table SET ".$key." = ".$value.";
```

change this to this

```
$sql ="UPDATE table SET '".$key."' = '".$value."';
```

and this

```
$value = "'".$value."'";
```

to this

```
$value = '".$value."';
```

one more think mysql_ function are depricited.

use mysqli_ Function or PDO

For mysqli_ function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

FOR PDO check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: This however does not solve the problem, as i said server does not support anything than mysql_query. thx

Comment: Then create a .sql file and import it to db from command line.

Comment: @cheery sorry but this is a creepy solution.

Comment: @im7xs Then you stay with the loop. What do you expect as an answer? mysql_ does not support multiple queries at one request.

Comment: @im7xs You did not explain the problem clearly. According to your code - you wanted each element of array into separate record in db. But if you would say that each element corresponds to the column in db - there will be no such long discussion.